# How do I create an object and define attributes with user input in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I am a beginner. Please bear with me.

My Vehicle class below has default attributes and I have created static methods that prompts the user for input.

class Vehicle:
""" Model a vehicle"""

```
def __init__(self, make='Chevy', model='Impala', color='Silver', fuelType='Regular'):
    """ Initialize vehicle attributes """
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
    self.fuelType = fuelType
   
@staticmethod
def getMake(self):
    self.make = input("Please enter your make ")
    return 
@staticmethod
def getModel(self, model):
    model = input("Please enter your model")
    return model
@staticmethod
def getColor(self, color):
    color = input("Please enter the color")
@staticmethod
def getFuelType(self, fuelType):
    fuelType = input("Please tell me your fuel type")
```

class car(Vehicle):

```
def __init__(self, make, model, color, fuelType):

    super().__init__(make, model, color, fuelType)

    """ Initialize car attributes"""

    self.engine_Size = engine_Size
    self.num_Doors = num_Doors

@staticmethod
def getEngineSize(self):
    self.engineSize = input("Please enter your engine size")
    return self.engineSize
@staticmethod    
def getNumDoors(self):
    self.numDoors = input("Please tell me how many doors you have")
    return self.numDoors
```

class pickup(Vehicle):

```
def __init__(self, cabStyle, bedLength):

    """ Initialize pickup attributes """

    self.cabStyle = cabStyle
    self.bedLength = bedLength

def getCabStyle(self):
    self.cabStyle = input("Please enter your engine size")
    return self.cabStyle
def getBedLength(self):
    self.bedLength = input("Please tell me how many doors you have")
    return self.bedLength
```

list = []

while True:

```
n = 1
VehicleType = input("Please select a car or pickup to add to your virtual garage ")

for i in range(0, n): 

    v = Vehicle()
    print(v)
    

    v.getMake()
    v.getModel()
    v.getColor()
    v.getFuelType()
    list.append(v)
    n = n + 1
  

    break
```

In my loop, I want to use the methods to get define my attributes of vehicle , then save to my list. Why am I getting the error "TypeError: getMake() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"? Everything I've read suggest I don't have to put self in the method when it's being called and when I do, I get the following error, "name 'self' is not defined"

Please help

Comment: You have to decide between using static or using self.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it for me.